# heroku run python manage.py migrate do not create table on heroku server

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

[this is image of my all project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrkpf.png)

heroku run manage.py migrate

```
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ bdsharma... up, run.9363 (Free)
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, shastri
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying shastri.0001_initial... OK
```

but these migrations are not applied in reality. It gives operational error while i run this on server.

```
OperationalError at /
no such table: shastri_occasion
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://bdsharma.herokuapp.com/
Django Version: 3.1.1
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: shastri_occasion
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py, line 413, in execute
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.12
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 10 Sep 2020 08:19:26 +0000
```

I have run migrate command many time on both heroku and local server but its not working.

Comment: Have you added your app to INSTALLED_APPS? Does your Heroku app on the server have the migration file on it, so the migrate command can use it to perform the migration?

Comment: yes i had added my app in installed app. But how do i check that wether heroku app have migration file or not ?

Comment: OK, have you ran make migrations and is the migrations file on the server? For example, you haven’t added it to a .slugignore or .gitignore with a hook setup?

Comment: yes , i had applied all migrations and it is not in .gitignore or .slugignore

Comment: do i need to inssall django-heroku?

Comment: I don’t install that, however I deploy using Docker.

Comment: I’m not sure now. It might help you to check your logs if you have the Heroku CLI installed. This is done with the command heroku logs —tail

Comment: Also, it might help if you connect your database to some database software. I use DataGrip but there are other free alternatives like Beekeeper Studio (for Mac). Not sure about Windows.

Comment: The error shows you are using `sqlite3`. You can't use `sqlite3` with Heroku because the filesystem is ephemeral. Switch to another database, for example postgreSQL (see the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-python)). Don't try to install `django-heroku`, it won't fix this error.